# The argument for the named parameter 'body' was already specified.What we should do when we have two "bodys' in a scaffold in flutter

Tags: flutter, scaffold

Error:  The argument for the named parameter 'body' was already specified.What we should do when we have two "bodys' in a scaffold in flutter

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text(widget.title),
                 ),
               body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: gridView(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

        body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child : Container(
               child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Enter the Device Details",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion can you be little more brief with an exmple or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title)),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: child: gridView(),
              ),
              Container(
               child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Enter the Device Details",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )
                    )
                  ]
                )
               )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my query ,but My Grid   is not shown when I chose gallery image or camera photo    child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: child: gridView(),
              ),   I have used image picker for Gallery and Camera images/photos

Comment: I do not understand exactly, please post the code and the error

Comment: I mean My App  show photos from Gallery  and Camera in Grid View at the begining, then the list view appaers  i.e starts from   Container(
               child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Enter the Device Details",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        
                      )
            etc.

Comment: My code is much longer is with List View Items  with 12 number of items , hence it should be scrollable and flexible. Please help

Comment: alecsam can I get your contact email id etc so that I can send my code and  get a fix from you to my issue.

Comment: First of all, this seems to be another issue. However, without a clear example, I can't implement your idea from the beginning. Maybe you can simplify your code and explain the error or what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is no error now, but only thing needed  is I want a scrollable list view under the Gridview     Flexible(
                child: child: gridView(),
              ),          That is in the next  Container with Children Widgets which is starting after the gridview.

Comment: `Expanded(child: Container(child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5), child: ListView(children: [Text("aaa"), Text("bbb"), Text("ccc"), Text("ddd"),],)))),`

Comment: Thank you very much alcesam. Thanks for being with me and supporting. It worked very well. Nice support from you.

Comment: Another Exception whenI try to retieve the text data after submit into sqflite.                                Another exception was thrown: SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.

Comment: You should open another issue and add relevant code.